# CSS Buttons on a hr line?

Tags: html, css

Hello once again everyone today i have a question regarding how to place some CSS buttons on a hr line. i have uploaded an example to my webserver. and again buttons on the line im also thinking of having multiple buttons.

I am only 13 so an explanation would be nice too ^_^ Thanks!
Buttons on line: http://dibjso.tk/projects/Stack/bonhr/bonhr.html

Code:

```
   <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                background-color: #E0E0E0;
                text-align: center;
            }
            h1{
                font-size: 75px;
            }
            hr{
                width: 85%;
            }
            .buttons{
                width: 65px;
                height: 35px;
                background-color: #B5B5B5;
                padding: 5px;
                border: 1px solid #000000;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .buttons:hover{
                background-color: #C4C4C4;
                border: 1.5px solid #171717;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>TITLE</h1>
         <hr size="0">
         <span class="buttons">Example Button</span>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand right, [this should do the trick](http://jsfiddle.net/7y4me/) the crucial thing is to give your buttons a `position:relative`, change them to `inline-block` and then provide a negative top offset.

What this does is specify that the button element should calculate its position relative to the preceding DOM elements / its parent(s), by setting the `top` to a minus value, it basically says relative to where the preceding element has 'finished' move the button up a bit, overlapping it. Setting `display:inline-block` allows us to apply this to the element as it only works for block elements, whilst retaining the desired behaviour that inline elements feature.

Comment: Ahh great, glad to help - let me know if you're unsure of anything. As far as your question goes, users get reputation for any 'up votes' as well as accepted answers (clicking the tick) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Comment: Thanks :) brill. i know alot of people struggled to get this answer in many different places we finally have it! Also im using a <span> for my button is there anything better i could use?

Comment: You should probably use the <button> element (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)

Comment: After clicked it displays an orange curved rectangular shape around it though. ive treid that :/ btw click the Link in my original post again :)